# Type safe binding to an Oracle Stored Procedure in C#?

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures

We are deploying multiple projects in C# with Oracle databases behind. I would like to implement all of the database logic in Oracle stored procedures as this

- keeps all of the database logic in the database
- makes it easier to maintain when database structures change
- allows re-use of the stored procedures more easily across programming languages

I have test code running where I return rows using a SYS_REFCURSOR and I manually do the data bind on the results as SYS_REFCURSOR could be returning anything - i.e. its not type safe

My question is - is there any way I can define correct types in the stored procedure return type and correctly bind to that type safely in my C# code?

e.g. my PL/SQL procedure looks like this - the return part is not type safe - it could be anything. If I wanted to re-use it from another Oracle package then it will not have the correct type checking

```
PROCEDURE get_risk (p_process_id IN NUMBER, p_risk OUT sys_refcursor);
```

and my C# code looks something like the following. I have cludged this together from several classes so hopefully it makes sense. When I extract the data from the DB call I am manually defining the data types - I need to know in the C# code what the Oracle data types are

```
// setup procedure call
_oracleCommand = new OracleCommand("risk_pkg.get_risk", _conn.OracleConnection);
_oracleCommand.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("p_process_id", OracleDbType.Int64, processId, ParameterDirection.Input));
_oracleCommand.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("p_risk", OracleDbType.RefCursor, null, ParameterDirection.Output));

_oracleDataAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter(_oracleCommand);
_dataSet = new DataSet();

// call Oracle
_oracleDataAdapter.Fill(_dataSet);

// extract data - hand coded binding
Int64 dbRiskId = (Int64)_dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0][_dataSet.Tables[0].Columns["risk_id"]];
Int64 dbClientId = (Int64)_dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0][_dataSet.Tables[0].Columns["client_id"]];

return new Risk(dbRiskId, dbClientId);
```

This isn't necessarily a problem - I just want to know if there is a better way of doing this to make my PL/SQL more obvious in what it is returning, and making my C# code not have to know the Oracle data types - encapsulating me from database structure changes

Accepted solution : this seems to be the practical solution. I'm still slightly unsatisfied that my Oracle procedure isn't defining its return type explicitly, but that life

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(You should post a sample of your to test code. Because I'm not sure, if I understand your question correctly.)

The returned type is `Object` to serve any possible return value. You have to convert it manually. But you could generate the code for the conversions. Define a table or a file with this meta information: which stored procedure returns which types and in which .Net types they shall be converted. Use this meta information to create the C# code.

We fill our RefCursors into a `DataTable`. The code to assign the table fields to their appropriate member variables is generated out of our meta tables.

Comment: This could be the way to go - I was looking for some way in which I could completely define the return type in the Oracle procedure. This would make any other code that talks to the procedure type safe as well. I guess the issue I have is that I am not completely defining the interface - I don't normally write functions and return an Object when I know what the data type actually is

Comment: Yes, define that interface. We support Oracle and SQL Server. We have for both one class which cares about db specific stuff. Both are implementing the same interface.

Comment: Do you return your data as SYS_REFCURSOR from Oracle?

Comment: No, as Ref Cursor: `TYPE resc IS REF CURSOR;` and `Procedure foo(bla in varchar2, bla2 in char, pResult IN OUT resc)` It wasn't possible to use Sys_refcursor. IIRC because we had to support Oracle 8 which does not support his. But I'm not sure. Do you think it makes a difference?

Answer (score 1):

I have used T4 text templating to do this with SQL server. Works incredibly well.